# Find Patterned Directory Path From File Path

Tags: regex, bash

I have file paths like the following:

```
/Users/admin/projects-FB9085/testing/tests/file/Library_Views_Mobile_Test.php
/Users/admin/projects-FB9085/applications/Views/Library_Views_Mobile.php
```

I'm trying to figure out a bash command that given the file path of the test can extract the projects directory like
`/Users/admin/projects-FB9085/` which is always of the pattern 'projects-FB' followed by a variable number of digits.

I've tried using `dirname` and `echo expr match` but I can't get the regex to work, and dirname got tricky with the variable number of subdirectories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from a string:

```
$ grep -o '^.*projects-FB[0-9]\+' <<< '/Users/admin/projects-FB9085/testing/tests/file/Library_Views_Mobile_Test.php'
/Users/admin/projects-FB9085

$ echo '/Users/admin/projects-FB9085/testing/tests/file/Library_Views_Mobile_Test.php' | grep -o '^.*projects-FB[0-9]\+'
/Users/admin/projects-FB9085
```

or, from a file

```
$ grep -o '^.*projects-FB[0-9]\+' infile.txt
```

The regex follows what you described in the question

- `^.*` matches any number of characters from the beginning
- `projects-FB` is your unique string
- `[0-9]\+` is one or more digits
- `grep -o` will print only the matching portions

Comment: works beautifully.  Thanks for the regex breakdown too.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty, but only uses builtins:

```
while read DIR; do
  DIR2="${dir#/Users/admin/projects-FB}";
  if [ "$DIR2" != "$DIR1" ]; then
    echo "/Users/admin/projects-FB${DIR2%%/*}/";
  fi;
done
```

With `sed`:

```
sed -n 's#^\(/Users/admin/projects-FB[0-9]\+\)/.*$#\1#p'
```

And with `expr` and you requested:

```
while read DIR; do
  expr "$DIR" : "\(/Users/admin/projects-FB[0-9]\+/\)";
done
```